# For/While Loop on variables that satisfy a certain condition [R]

Tags: r, if-statement

urI'm trying to write a if else statement (ultimately) in R, but only for variables that satisfy a certain criteria.  I'm sure there is an easy way to do this - but can't seem to find anything specific when searching...

Below is an example of a while loop (not sure whether I can use this for this purpose):

```
while(gene[c(36)] >=30 & gene[c(37)] >=30 & gene[c(38)] >=30)
{
gene$Category <- ifelse((gene[c(49)] == './.' & gene[c(48)] == './.'), 'N/A',     ifelse(((gene[c(50)] == './.') & (gene[c(36)] >=30 & gene[c(37)] >=30)),'denovo deletion',''))
}
```

I technically want to run the if else statement on a variable(s) only if certain other conditions are met.  Am I overly complicating this?

Comment: Why use a while loop? When will this loop exit?

Comment: Wasn't understanding the while statement correctly when trying to figure this out... but eventually did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your `ifelse` construct is OK, you can "subset" the frame based on the condition that is now expressed in your `while` loop:

```
condition = (gene[36] >=30 & gene[37] >=30 & gene[38] >=30)
gene$Category[condition] <- ifelse((gene[49] == './.' & gene[48] == './.'), 'N/A', ifelse(((gene[50] == './.') & (gene[36] >=30 & gene[37] >=30)),'denovo deletion',''))
```